# Do car manufacturers provide specific make/model/year information for each diagnostic-trouble-code?

Tags: troubleshooting, obd-ii, dtc

Recently my car's check-engine light came on, I used a car OBDII port code reader to get the diagnostic-trouble-code (DTC) and then I googled what the DTC meant. I noticed that lots of the websites and searches are specific to a make (i.e. Mazda, Honda, etc).

**Do car manufacturers provide specific make/model/year information for each diagnostic-trouble-code? Or is it only for make/model? or maybe only specific for the car make (i.e. Mazda, Honda, etc)?**

**If yes, where is this information officially published by the car manufacturer (is it on the car manufacturer's website or only available to dealers via some non-disclosure-agreement/agreement/special-access)?**

It's hard to find good information about the diagnostic trouble codes when you get one on your car. So if there is some "official" documentation I can look up for my make/model/year then I want to find that... instead of some random website that has unverified/unknown-quality information/advice about something important (what is wrong with my car and how to fix the car).

Answer (score 3):

Some parts of the OBD-II code are the same for every vehicle (year/make/model independent), while others can be specific to a make and/or model. The year is usually irrelevant, though there has been some amount of change since OBD-II standards have been implemented. The website [OBD-Codes.com](http://www.obd-codes.com/faq/obd2-codes-explained.php) explains the breakdown fairly well:

> The first character identifies identifies the system related to the trouble code.
>
> - P = Powertrain
> - B = Body
> - C = Chassis
> - U = Undefined
>
> The second digit identifies whether the code is a generic code (same on all OBD-II equpped vehicles), or a manufacturer specific code.
>
> - 0 = Generic (this is the digit zero -- not the letter "O")
> - 1 = Enhanced (manufacturer specific)
>
> The third digit denotes the type of sub-system that pertains to the code
>
> - 1 = Emission Management (Fuel or Air)
> - 2 = Injector Circuit (Fuel or Air)
> - 3 = Ignition or Misfire
> - 4 = Emission Control
> - 5 = Vehicle Speed & Idle Control
> - 6 = Computer & Output Circuit
> - 7 = Transmission
> - 8 = Transmission
> - 9 = SAE Reserved
> - 0 = SAE Reserved
>
> The fourth and fifth digits, are variable, and relate to a particular problem. For instance, P0171 code means [P0171 - System Too Lean (Bank 1)](http://www.obd-codes.com/p0171). To lookup your particular code, visit our [OBD Trouble Codes section](http://www.obd-codes.com/trouble_codes/).

I've found OBD-Codes.com and [engine-codes.com](http://www.engine-codes.com/) to both have a lot of good information on them. Not every code will be listed, but you can usually find the codes by doing a google search using the code itself (ie: P0171) and the words "OBD-II code" or something very similar. I'm sure that some of the manufacturers would sell you a subscription to get the information, but you'll find with the right Google-Fu you can find the information you are looking for ... or you can always come here and get an answer :D